# How to avoid the percent encoding in a string?

Tags: string, swift, encoding, nsurl, uiactivityviewcontroller

I would like to export some stuff from my app using an UIActivityViewController. 
I have a NSURL among other things (which works perfectly when I choose to export to my reading list), but when I opt to send an email, the link that is printed in the email's body is messed up by the encoding.

Part of the link says: "...&origem=TODOS&regiao=QUALQUER..." which is converted to: "...&origem=TODOS®iao=QUALQUER...". This action makes my link a non-clickable one, and I must guarantee this action to the user.

How can I avoid this? Is there a way to not print the NSURL in the email body ?

Also, when I print the link to the console this problem does not occur.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

```
@IBAction func exportWebButton(sender: AnyObject) {

// some code here > generating testData.pdf

    let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [testData,NSURL(string:self.url)!], applicationActivities: nil) 

    print(NSURL(string:self.url)!) //> "...&origem=TODOS&regiao=QUALQUER..."

    let presentationController = activityController.popoverPresentationController

    presentationController?.barButtonItem = self.exportWebButtonO

    self.presentViewController(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Can you post what you've coded so far ?

Comment: The issue seems to be related to some autocorrection rather than URL percent encoding

Comment: Sounds like your body is being interpreted as HTML. If you're sending HTML emails, you need to appropriately *HTML escape/encode* all characters which have a special meaning in HTML.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding